# How can I use Visual Studio 2010 for C development?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, development-environment, compilation

I would like to do some C development in Windows environment using Visual Studio 2010. There are a few similar questions on this topic, but they are all based on that you are creating a Win32 console application, and a C++ project.

How can I do C development using only `.c` and `.h` files as I do in Unix? **without creating a C++ projects containing tons of files.**

It is possible to do C compiling with the [`cl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx) compiler from outside of Visual Studio 2010, see [Walkthrough: Compiling a C Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx). But how can I do this compilation and execution/debugging from inside Visual Studio 2010?

**UPDATE**

- I have tried to create a C++ project (Win32 Console Application) and only add `.c` files to it. It works but it creates tons of files.
- I have tried with a C++ project (Empty project), but it also created a lot of project files.
- Basically what I want is to only create `.c` and `.h` files, use the [`cl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx) compiler, and use Visual Studio 2010 as a text editor. And use a command to compile from the text edior, but it seems like I have to compile in a command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile a file that has the .c extension, VS will use it's C compiler. However, you should be aware that said C compiler isn't C99 conformant (or even C89 for some cases, if I remember correctly). Visual Studio is not really a C compiler, it's C++ mostly. You will have to use a C++ project and simply include .c files.

Comment: Err.. it's most definitely a C compiler. Windows is compiled with something. ;) Though there are some nonstandard extensions, like every compiler has.

Comment: Is this really the only way? By creating a C++ project, I create tons of different files. Using the article I linked to, only a `.c` file, an `.obj` file and an `.exe` file is created.

Comment: @Jonas: Many extras are created with a project, like Intellisense databases, partial rebuild files, etc. All of these files have uses that your article can't match. Whether or not you actually use them is another matter. What you should do is ignore the extra files unless they take up excessive space or your builds stop working. Until then, ignore. @Billy ONeal: Yeah, the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 9):

1. File → New → Project...
2. Under C++, choose Empty Project. If you want to minimize the number of folders created, uncheck the box to Create Directory for Solution. Give the project a name and location and click OK.
3. In the Solution Explorer for the new project, right click Source Files and select Add → New Item.
4. Choose C++ File (.cpp), and give it a name like `SomeName.c`. ***Make sure to specify the `.c` extension.*** Add the following code:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```
5. If necessary, disable Microsoft extensions to the C language by right clicking the project and selecting Properties. Select All Configurations at the top of the dialog. Then go to C/C++ → Language → Disable Language Extensions: Yes.

Visual Studio will create the following files for your project. Just get used to having them there. **Do not check items with a * into source control.**

- ProjectName.sln
- ProjectName.sdf*
- ProjectName.suo*
- ProjectName.vcxproj
- ProjectName.vcxproj.user*
- ProjectName.vcxproj.filters
- somename.c

Comment: +1. Also note that anything in the ipch directory and any file with a .ncb extension should also be excluded from source control.

Answer (score 1):

VS actually has a very capable C compiler, somethng that people overlook all too often. The above answers will point you in the right direction, but it's by no means low quality like I've heard people say in the past.